# Why is "Unlock to Share" showing up when trying to "Share my Screen" in FaceTime?

Tags: iphone, ios, facetime

I often help my mother with her iPhone by asking her to "Share my Screen" during FaceTime video calls.
However when she taps the Share icon, and then taps "Share my Screen", she is presented with a message saying "Unlock to Share" (we are both using iOS 16.5.1)

Obviously her screen is unlocked, otherwise she wouldn't be able to see the FaceTime screen.
I am unable to reproduce this on my end. I get the expected behaviour: When I tap the Share icon, a small window appears with "Share my Screen" as the option on top. I tap this and after 3 seconds the screen share begins.

Why is the "Unlock to Share" message appearing?
How can I prevent this from appearing to make it easier for her to share her screen?

Answer (score 8):

> Obviously her screen is unlocked, otherwise she wouldn't be able to see the FaceTime screen.

This is not true in isolation. One can answer an incoming FaceTime call without unlocking the device, and the device will remain locked during the call.

Like a phone call, a FaceTime call does not require a Face ID or passcode check to ‘slide to accept’ when the phone is ringing.

It's therefore possible your mother has answered your call and not unlocked the device. Trying to share screen will then show this prompt to ‘Unlock to Share’.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it was possible to answer FaceTime without unlocking device.